# Adding product to table cart with trigger in c# (it wont close automatically )

Tags: c#

When I try to enter quantity to add to table cart in my pos form it wont accept or close accepting values after I enter them. the quantity should be updated in the cart table listing all the details but nothing happens after I enter the quantity in the pop up when the barcode is scanned I need your support guys...

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace POSsystem
{
public partial class frmQty : Form
{
//code to connect sql database 
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
DBConnection dbcon = new DBConnection();
SqlDataReader dr;
private String pcode;
private double price;
private string transno;
string stitle = "Simple POS System";
frmPOS fpos;
public frmQty(frmPOS frmpos)
{
InitializeComponent();
cn = new SqlConnection(dbcon.MyConnection());
fpos = frmpos;
}
private void frmQty_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
public void ProductDetails(String pcode, double price, String transno)
{
this.pcode = pcode;
this.price = price;
this.transno = transno;
}
private void frmQty_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
if ((e.KeyChar == 13) && (txtQty.Text != String.Empty))
{
cn.Open();
cm = new SqlCommand("insert into tblcart (transno, pcode, price, qty,     
sdate)values(@transno, @pcode, @price, @qty, @sdate", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transno", transno);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pcode", pcode);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", price);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", int.Parse(txtQty.Text));
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sdate", DateTime.Now);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            

            fpos.txtSearch.Clear();
            fpos.txtSearch.Focus();
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
}
`
```

Comment: This question isn't related to the Visual Studio application, so I've removed that tag for you. Please remember to read tag descriptions carefully before using them.

Comment: Ok i will keep that in mind..thank you

Comment: Without more info, it is difficult to understand what is not happening as expected. However, it appears the “FORMS” `frmQty_KeyPress` event is wired up do most of the work. Are you sure that event is firing as you are expecting? Have you put a break point in the event?

Comment: no the program runs fine only problem is when I type quantity like 5 it should close and update the cart column but its not closing after I type the quantity amount and presses enter.

Comment: Have you put a break point on the line `this.Dispose()`? If that line executes, then the form should close. Since you say the form does not close, then that is why I was asking if the event is getting fired. If the event fires AND the text box `txtQty` is not empty AND the user pressed the “Enter” key… then the form “should” close. But this is not what is happening according to you. So, it would appear clear that the line of code …`this.Dispose()` … is NOT getting executed.

Comment: That is why I suggest you put a break point on the line `if ((e.KeyChar == 13) && (txtQty.Text != String.Empty))…` … and run the code. If the break point gets hit and stops execution at that line, then this will confirm that the event IS firing. If the break point never gets hit, then this will confirm that the event is NOT getting fired (which I feel is the case).

Comment: If the break point DOES get hit and stops execution on that line, then this confirms the event DOES fire. If it does fire, then step through the code to get to the line… `this.Dispose()` …, if it gets to that line and executes the dispose method (which will close the form) AND the form DOES NOT close… then that is a problem. However, I feel confident that the line is never executed.

Comment: To clarify, the reason I am suggesting this is because when the form loaded, it most likely has other controls on the form… like the text box. After the form is initialized and the control is given to the user, then “usually” the focus will NOT be on the FORM itself. The focus is usually on one of the controls on the form… like the text box.

Comment: So, in this case, if the text box has focus, and the user presses the “Enter” key… then the FORMS `KeyPress` event will NOT fire. However, the `TextBoxes` `KeyPress` event WILL fire. So, I am suggesting that you are using the wrong event for this. I would suggest that to get this to work, you need to wire up the `TextBoxes` `KeyPress` event instead of the FORMS `keyPress` event. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: yeah i understand thanks..i will try this solution and let you know...you are awesome

Comment: i tried it and it worked but now the data is not showing on tblcart in sql as it should..

Comment: but the breakpoint is executing in at if ((e.KeyChar == 13) && (txtQty.Text != String.Empty))

Comment: now it shows incorrect syntax near sdate..